# Splitting array of objects and then process it in batches

Tags: c#, arrays

What would be a good way to call the `Execute` method in batches of `rulesObjs`? Lets say the list have more than 10,000 objects and I want to call `Execute` with no more than 500 at a time.

```
    public static List<object> ExecutePolicy()
    {
        Policy policy = new Policy();

        List<object> rules = GetRules();

        object[] rulesObjs = rules.ToArray();

        // Call this method with array of object, but in batches.
        policy.Execute(rulesObjs);

        return rulesObjs.ToList();
    }

    private static List<object> GetRules()
    {
        // get the rules via some process
        return new List<object>();
    }
}

public sealed class Policy
{
    public void Execute(params object[] rules)
    {
        // Process rules...
    }
}
```

I do not have control over `Execute()` method.

Comment: I think you can use morelinq's [Batch](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Batch.cs?r=f85495b139a19bce7df2be98ad88754ba8932a28) for this.

Comment: L.B's suggestion would be that much more useful if `GetRules` returned an `IEnumerable`, rather than a list, and streamed its results rather than eagerly evaluating the whole thing.

Comment: @Servy I said it not performance wise, just for cleaner code. And it is  not worse than calling the `GetEnumerator` in the loop for `Skip`s and `Take`s

Comment: @L.B Agreed.  The two options are more or less the same when called on a `List`.  If you already have `MoreLinq` in your solution then I would use `Batch`, if you don't then `Skip` and `Take` would be quicker/easier for me.  If the source was streamed, then MoreLinq's `Batch` would be significantly better than skip/take.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
List<object> rules = GetRules();
int batchSize = 500;
int currentBatch = 0;

while (currentBatch * batchSize < rules.Count)
{
    object[] nextBatch = rules.Skip(currentBatch * batchSize)
        .Take(batchSize).ToArray();
    //use batch
    currentBatch++;
}
```

Comment: +1 : One issue with this is if `rules.Count % batchSize` is not 0, it will throw an exception on `.Take(batchSize)`

Comment: @VoodooChild No it wont.  `Take` is implemented such that if you try to take more items than the collection has it will simply return all of the items that are there.

Comment: Skip is also implemented such that if you try to skip more items than the collection has it will simply return an empty enumerable, although I've written the code such that it shouldn't ever happen here.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you have control over the `Execute()` method, the best way to do it would be to pass an index to that method so that it knows at which index of the array to start at.

```
public void Execute(int startIndex, /*optional*/ int endIndex, params object[] rules)
{
    // Process rules...
}
```

Don't worry about passing too much data at once.  Behind the scenes, your array is just a pointer, so you're only passing a reference anyways.

If you don't have control over the `Execute()` method, then you can make a new array for your section, using [Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx), and process that new array.

Comment: I do not have control over `Execute()` method, updated my question to point it out.

Answer (score 2):

With a reference to `System.Linq` you can use skip and take:

```
int total = 10000;
int chunkSize = 500;
for (int i = 0; i < total; i += chunkSize )
{
    var chunk = rulesObjs.Skip(i).Take(chunkSize).ToArray();

    policy.Execute(chunk);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use new method

`Enumerable.Chunk(items, 50)`

like

```cs
List<object> rules = GetRules();

foreach (var batch in rules.Chunk(50))
{
    // Call this method with array of object, but in batches.
    policy.Execute(batch.ToArray());
}

return rules;
```